# thymeleaf show specific user profile

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, user-profile

Im new to thymeleaf and spring boot so I don't really know what I'm looking for to solve my problem.
I have several users shown in a list on my website. When I click on one of the users, I want to display the users profile page.

The list looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="section : ${sections}">
        <a href="overviewDivision.html?id=1" th:href="@{/overviewDivision?id=1}">
            <span th:text="${section.name}">Bereich3</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li th:each="person : ${personSectionService.getPersonsBySectionId(section.id)}">
                <a href="overviewEmployee.html?id= + person.id" th:href="@{/overviewEmployee?id= + person.id}">
                    <span th:text="${person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName}">
                    </span>
               </a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/overviewEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String overviewEmployee(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("sections", sectionService.getAllSections());
    model.addAttribute("personSectionService", personSectionService);
    model.addAttribute("currentPerson", personService.getById(1));
    return "overviewEmployee";
}
```

On the profile page I use currentPerson.firstName and so on to get the information about the user.
So my question is, how do I change the currentPerson into the last clicked person in the list? Or am I doing it totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 2 handlers for that: one to display your list, and one to get the detail. The former should not set the `currentPerson` in the model, because you don't have this information yet.

Your handlers should look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String overviewEmployee(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("sections", sectionService.getAllSections());
    model.addAttribute("personSectionService", personSectionService);
    return "employee-list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/overviewEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String overviewEmployee(Model model, @RequestParameter long id) {
    model.addAttribute("currentPerson", personService.getById(id));
    return "overviewEmployee";
}
```

(Notice the use of `@RequestParameter`)

I'm assuming your `id` is a `long`, and that it's mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

: Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'jobId' for method parameter type String is not present]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).